# Picker Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I'm having some difficulty with a class project of mine. I need to create a view with a picker with two components. As I select the row in the first component, it needs to update the options of the second component. My issue is that I am getting an out of bounds exception when moving both components at the same time. Any tips?

There is code for a slider that additionally updates as the picker updates and vice versa. My code is:

```
import UIKit
 class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var FoodPicker: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var FoodSlider: UISlider!

let Countries = ["India","USA","Mexico"]
let IndianFood = ["Avakaya","Pesarattu","Thukpa","Thali","Litti Chokha","Maple","Palak Paneer","Rajma-Shawl","Vindaloo","Khaman","Handva","Bisi bele bath","Pav Bhaji","Eromba","Chungdi Jhola"]
let USFood = ["Hot Dog","Pizza","Hamburger","Clam Chowder","Succotash","Fried Chicken","Gumbo","Grits","Chitterlings","Hushpuppies","Cobbler"]
let MexicanFood = ["Taco","Quesadilla","Pambazo","tamal","huarache","Alambre","Enchilada","Panita","Gordita","Tlayuda","Sincronizada"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FoodPicker.dataSource = self
    FoodPicker.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: - Picker Creation
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    switch component {
    case 1:
        switch FoodPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) {
        case 1:
            return USFood.count
        case 2:
            return MexicanFood.count
        default:
            return IndianFood.count
        }
    default:
        return Countries.count
    }
}

//MARK: - Picker Delegate
//returns picker row names
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch component {
    case 1:
        switch FoodPicker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) {
        case 1:
            return USFood[row]
        case 2:
            return MexicanFood[row]
        default:
            return IndianFood[row]
        }
    default:
        return Countries[row]
    }
}

//MARK: - Picker Updater
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if 0==component {
        FoodPicker.reloadComponent(1)
        switch row {
        case 1:
            FoodSlider.maximumValue = Float(USFood.count-1)
        case 2:
            FoodSlider.maximumValue = Float(MexicanFood.count-1)
        default:
            FoodSlider.maximumValue = Float(IndianFood.count-1)
        }
    }
    if 1==component {
        FoodSlider.setValue(Float(row), animated: true)
    }
}

@IBAction func sliderSelector(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    FoodPicker.selectRow(Int(FoodSlider.value), inComponent: 1, animated: true)
}
}
```

Error coming up is:

```
2016-10-26 21:21:15.943915 assignment4[10836:5039575] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Feedback, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)
```

Comment: What is the complete and exact error message? Which line is causing the error? Please put this info in your question (do not post them as a comment).

Comment: Added in the error at the bottom of the post. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: None of that is the relevant info asked for.

Comment: Could I ask specifically what you're asking for? The error is I am getting an out of bounds error. I'm trying to figure out how to stop that. I added in the error from the console.

Comment: Please post the code, which action  launching the picker ?. add exception breakpoint  and check the crashing line

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the reason for crash occurs on the below line

```
@IBAction func sliderSelector(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    FoodPicker.selectRow(Int(FoodSlider.value), inComponent: 1, animated: true)
}
```

If you are setting int value of more than 2 ranging from 0 in the above line . then you will get the above error .Because  component 1 of picker has array of count 3 only